# Magento from Admin to Setup Wizard introduces a 401 page

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard

When I want to access to Web Setup Wizard from Admin Panel (*system / tools / Web Setup Wizard*), I obtain this message:

> Magento Setup 401 Unauthorized Access

I have nevertheless all the rights as user administrator!

Any Ideas,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came of the version of Magento.

First, i used the 2.0.0 version - i uninstalled it and reinstalled the 2.0.2 version => it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

- Base URLs (Secure)
  -> Use Secure URLs on Storefront -> Yes

  -> Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes

  -> Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) -> Yes

  -> Upgrade Insecure Requests -> Yes

php bin/magento cache:clean

https://yadi.sk/i/iPJi4k7X3S86Za

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your cookies for the particular domain. This worked for me.